# how to use sql query in powershell if $ (dollar) in query

Tags: powershell

This might sound stupid but i am facing some issue with Oracle query and powershell.

Query is below.

```
$sql="select * from v$dbase"
```

This is the output if i check in powershell.

```
select * from v
```

But powershell is not recognising it and consider it as variable due to **$** this.

Can anybody advise me how can i fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$sql='select * from v$dbase'
```

Another way is to escape the `$` using the escape character **`**

```
"select * from v`$dbase"
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for quick reply. I tried multiple things but didn't tried this.